# Angular : pass parameter to controller from $routeProvider.when

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, angular-controller

I perform a routing upon a broadcast and I need to pass a parameter from $rootScope.$on to a controller through routing.

```
$rootScope.$on('unauthorized_access', function (event, args) {
    $location.path('/login:' + args.msg);
});
```

Now, this is working.

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'mainApp/landingPage/login.html'
})
.when('/login::msg', {
    templateUrl: function(params) {
        if (params) {
            // The params can be printed in console from here...
            console.log(params);
        }
        return 'mainApp/landingPage/login.html';
    },
    controller: 'loginController'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

Now, so far it seems okay. But I need to pass the params to loginController. I tried,

```
.when('/login::msg', {
    templateUrl: function(params) {
        if (params) {
            console.log(params);
        }
        return 'mainApp/landingPage/login.html';
    },
    controller: 'loginController',
    pageParams : params
})
```

but I think, I am doing it wrong. Please help me. Any helps is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT : I will add a scenario. I need to pass a message-string to loginController from any screen when the 'token' becomes invalid after a fixed time and user is redirected to login screen. Now, when the user arrives for the first time, there is no message to be shown.
Hence, this is how I pass the message to broadcast

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('unauthorized_access', param);
```

Comment: it's better to watch the session consistence with http interceptors. When you are getting 401 error, you can kill your session and redirect user to login page

Comment: yes, that's what I am doing. But I need to pass a message as well. So I put that message(which caused the redirection) through the broadcast. This is my service to redirect on 401 error.
service.responseError = function(resp) {
    var param = {};
    if(resp.error == 401){
        param.msg = "Token Expired";
    }
    $rootScope.$broadcast('unauthorized_access', param);
    return resp;
};

Comment: then try resolve:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use resolve:

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/news", {
        templateUrl: "newsView.html",
        controller: "newsController",
        resolve: {
            message: function(messageService){
                return messageService.getMessage();
        }
    }
});
```

Then in your controller, you can get the data like below:

```
app.controller("newsController", function (message) {
    $scope.message = message;
});
```

More on this:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Comment: Thank you Thalaivar, that was exactly, I was looking for. Me too a Rajani fan. Waiting for Kabali.. thnks for swift answer. I will mark yours as accepted.